# Does the C++ standard allow using a typedef to rename a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, typedef

I was surprised to find that in VC++ 10, you can use a typedef to change the name of a class's constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
private:
    typedef A alias;

public:
    alias() { cout << "A ctor" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A(); // prints "A ctor"
    return 0;
}
```

Is this standard C++ or a Microsoft extension?

Comment: Not sure on the standard, but g++ and clang++ both error on this code.

Comment: g++ returns `ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘alias’ with no type`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No; constructors *do not have a name*. You cannot take the address of a constructor or pass a function pointer around, or even just *call* it like a normal function. The syntax `A::A()` is just a special declarator syntax that allows you to declare and define the constructors, but it isn't a *name*.

That said, you cannot typedef *objects* (including function pointers) anyway, only *types*.

To comment on the MSVC behaviour, I quote from 12.1/3:

> A *typedef-name* shall not be used [...] for a constructor declaration.

Comment: The same is for dtor.